# How long is the customs process in Indira Gandhi International Airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, new-delhi, del, leh-india, goair

I will arrive at Delhi Indira Gandhi International Airport at 2:45 AM, I plan to book my next domestic flight to Leh with GoAir which will depart at 8:30 AM. Is 5 hours enough time to clear all the customs and go to the domestic airport?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Customs at Indira Gandhi Airport, New Delhi is fairly fast, especially in very early morning in your case. I have been done International to Domestic Transfers in 1-1.5 hours. Since yours is on non-peak time, it should be even faster for you.

Unless your incoming flight is significantly delayed, you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Same experience.

Comment: thank you for the clear answer. BTW I use the e-visa so I heard it will take more time.

Comment: I am an Indian citizen. E-visa have one separate queue. Its quite unlikely to take more time, especially in early morning.

Comment: We did e-Visa entry three weeks ago, same time in the morning. Took less than 20 minutes from getting in line to walking out. Customs is simply walking through.